# How to show continuous serial number in pagination using django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a blog list layout. Now i am using `{{forloop.counter}}` in my template to generate serial numbers and it is working perfectly. Page 1 shows 1 - 20 serial number, then page 2 shows again 1 - 20 serial numbers. but i want to show serial number from 21 - 40 in page 2 and so on.. instead of 1 - 20 again and again in every page. How to do this using django.

Below is the portion of my template code.

```
{% for blog in all_blogs %}
<tr>
  <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
  <td>{{blog.category}}</td>
  <td>{{blog.title}}</td>
  <td>{{blog.published_date}}</td>
  <td>{{blog.views}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: could you add the complete code?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated the my question. Please check.

Comment: Do you have access to the number of the page in the template? if it is, please added to the question.

Comment: You have the pagination index so you have the page number then you can calculate the real id for each row by id = pagination index *  20 + forloop.counter

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:** Your serial number generated from `{{forloop.counter}}` based on current page data.

**Probable Solution:**

1. You can use `{{obj.id}}` so that DB primary key will be displayed as a serial number.
2. You can make another field in the database to maintain a serial number based on your requirements.
3. You can write Django custom template tags to calculate the serial number from  `{{forloop.counter}}` or based on your context.

Best of luck :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think you didn't get my point.